# リストボックスの値を呼び出し元のフォームにあるラベルに表示

Tags: vb.net

**前提**

1. form1にラベルとボタンを配置
2. ボタンクリックでform2を表示
3. form2にはデータを設定したリストボックスを配置済み

**質問**
form2のリストボックスのある行を選択した時、その行にあるデータをform1のラベルにセットしたい

**コード**

```
sub listbox1_click
  form1.label1.text = listbox1.selectitem
end sub
```

**結果**

> error BC30469: 非共有メンバーを参照するには、オブジェクト参照が必要です。

広域変数を用意した別モジュールを作成して、その中でform2を呼び出してデータを受け渡す方法を考えていますが、form2だけで完結する記述方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず前提知識としてVB.NETでWindows Formsアプリケーションを作成した場合、フォームのデフォルトインスタンスと呼ばれるものが生成されます。これにより`Form`に定義されているインスタンスメンバーに`Shared`の文法でアクセスできます。おそらく質問のコードでは

```
Form2.Show()
```

のような呼び出しがあると思われますが、これは実質的に

```
My.Forms.Form2.Show()
```

という処理です。同様に`Form1`のインスタンスメンバーには`My.Forms.Form1`からアクセスすればよく、`Form1.Label1`のアクセスレベルは既定では`Friend`ですので単純に`Form2`内から

```
My.Forms.Form1.Label.Text = "test"
```

のように記述するのがVB.NETのコンテキストでは一番簡潔になります。

---

なおVB.NETのアプリケーションフレームワークに依存しないコードの場合は

- `Form2`に目的の値(コントロール自体ではなく)を公開するプロパティを定義する
- `Form2`をモードレス(`form.Show()`)で表示する場合、上記プロパティの変更イベントを定義する
- `Form1`側で`ShowDialog`終了時または上記イベント発生時にプロパティ値を読み出すコードを記述する

のがベストだと思います。この方針であれば`Form1`に関する処理を`Form2`に記述する必要がありませんし、`Form2`のコントロールを`Form1`に対して隠ぺいすることもできます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
デフォルトインスタントに関しては不勉強でした。
本来ならフレームワークに依存しない記述がベストだと思いますが、今回はこちらの方法で実装しておきます。
開発環境についての記載がなかったこと、お詫びいたします。